# Meteor AutoForm - Is it possible to manually call the onSuccess or onError hooks?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

I have this form that checks for the user's CAPTCHA input. When the CAPTCHA is valid, it should send an e-mail, otherwise it should display an error.

```
AutoForm.addHooks(["form1", "form2", "form3"], {

    onSubmit: function(doc) {

        Meteor.call('validateCaptcha', formData, function(error, result) {

            if (result.success == true) {
                Meteor.call('sendEmail', doc);
            } else {
                Recaptcha.reload();
                // call onError here
                console.log("Error!");
            }

        });
    },

    onSuccess: function(operation, result, template) {
        // display success, reset form status
        console.log("CAPTCHA Validation Success! Email Sent!");
    }, 

    onError: function(operation, error, template) {
        // display error, reset form status
        console.log("Error: CAPTCHA Validation failed!");
    }
}
```

Now the problem with my code is that when the user submits a correct CAPTCHA, the code will send an e-mail but does not trigger the `onSuccess()` hook.

The same goes with when the user submits a wrong CAPTCHA. It displays my error message but does not trigger the `onError()` hook.

Is there a way to manually call these hooks?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [AutoForm hooks documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks), `onSuccess` and `onError` are called on successful or failed operations, not including `onSubmit`:

```
// Called when any operation succeeds, where operation will be
// "insert", "update", "remove", or the method name.
onSuccess: function(operation, result, template) {}, 

// Called when any operation fails, where operation will be
// "validation", "insert", "update", "remove", or the method name.
onError: function(operation, error, template) {},
```

If you need to handle success/failure cases for `onSubmit`, you should do so in your `if (result.success === true) ... else` code directly. You could also handle both the success and error cases in `after` hooks on a per-operation basis, if you want more granular control.